# Combining multiple data rows on key lookup

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I am trying to combine multiple CSV files. I have one csv with a current part number list of products we stock. Sorry, I can't embedded images as I am new. I've seen many similar posts but not any with both a merge and a groupby together.

[current_products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5C5s.png)

I have another csv with a list of image files that are associated with that part but are split up on to multiple rows. This list also has many more parts listed than we offer so merging based on the current_products sku is important.

[product_images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TZp.png)

I would like to reference the first csv for parts I currently use and combine the images files in the following format.

[newestproducts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yewJr.png)

I get a AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'to_csv', although when I just print the output in the terminal it appears to be the way I want it.

```
current_products = 'currentproducts.csv'
product_images = 'productimages.csv'
image_list = 'newestproducts.csv'

df_currentproducts = pd.read_csv(currentproducts)
df_product_images = pd.read_csv(product_images)

df_current_products['sku'] = df_currentproducts['sku'].astype(str)
df_product_images['sku'] = df_product_images['sku'].astype(str)

df_merged = pd.merge(df_current_products, df_product_images[['sku','images']], on = 'sku', how='left')

df_output = df_merged.groupby(['sku'])['images_y'].apply('&&'.join).reset_index

#print(df_output)
df_output.to_csv(image_list, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are missing `()` after `reset_index`:

```py
df_output = df_merged.groupby(['sku']['images_y'].apply('&&'.join).reset_index()
```

That resulted `df_output` type to method rather then a dataframe (just print `type(df_output)` to see that), so obviously he doesn't know any method named to_csv